# Would we have communication theory and systems without trignometric ratio?

Tags: communication, frequency, fourier, spectrum

Trigonometric identities happen to be invented for triangles: sin, cosine and through them tangent.

Later at school I learnt that they are periodic and have wave appearance. Than in University I came across a new topic, the Fourier series that depends on sin and cosine. At the end I was exposed to Fourier transform and how than DFT and how central it is to the communication theory.

--> My question is this, and I REALLY want a big answer to it since I have thought about it for some years. If mankind had not developed trigonometric ratios for triangles, we would not have fourier series and fourier transform (originally a method for the heat differential equation) and thus not have concept of frequency spectrum. Would it also mean that the wave equation would not exist? In terms of the advancement mankind has made e.g through frequency analysis, communication systems and radars, telephones and internet and much more. Would all this not have developed if trigonometric rations did not exist?

Comment: This question isn't a very good fit for this site.  It's not really clear if you are asking about the math or the physical laws which it models, but regardless it is more a question of philosophy than of engineering.

Comment: OK I will summarize my question. A lot of what we have developed today comes from the communications theory which gave a big push to electronics itself. If trig ratios did not exist, will all this science and technology depending on communications theory be around?

Comment: It still doesn't have anything to do with electronic design.

Comment: But what are trig ratios?  Math, or reality?  Does physics exist in a universe where its details preclude the existence of intelligent beings who could develop mathematical notation?  This is philosophy, not engineering.

Comment: Any answer would be pointless speculation at best, since there would be no way to prove or disprove it.  We are where we are, we can't go back and re-run history to see how things might be different.  Move along.

Comment: Speaking as a philosophy graduate, the question isn't even philosophical. It's just completely pointless. Trigonometry precedes Fourier series; triangles precede trigonometry; thinking in concepts precedes the lot of it. So?

Comment: I personally think that all this technology stuff is rooted in the fact that we have opposable thumbs.

Comment: Actually the assumption in the question is wrong. The earliest radio communication consisted of using sparks to generate random hash that propagated through space, and crude detectors. Nothing to do with nice sine waves.

Answer (score 4):

We did not invent trigonometric ratios.  They were already there, and we simply discovered them.  I hope you aren't proposing a world where trig didn't actually work.  I have no answer for that.

What you will find is that all of these observations and methods are interrelated.  Every time you learn of a new method, you will find parts of other methods being used.  Sometimes you'll find the same thing, but done another way.

If we didn't have trigonometry, we would have discovered it after working on the other problems.

Answer (score 3):

Human have had a innate understanding of frequency for a long time, probably since Caveman days.  Even today, other animals understand the rising and falling pitch of bird calls and whale songs.  None of these had Fourier transforms.

The cool thing about science is that it does not rely on your belief, faith, or your understanding for it to work.